# Given the List<String> need to sort it in given alphabetical order using stream and comparator

Tags: java, list, java-stream, comparator

given list and set of letters to sort the list using java stream

```
List<String> names= Arrays.asList("Robin","Zax","John");
String order = "ZALBKNDWMTFCGOIUHEPQXSYVRJ";
```

EXAMPLE:
Input:
List names= Arrays.asList("Robin","Zax","John");
String order = "ZJR"

Output: ["Zax","John","Robin"]

Input 2:
 `List<String> names= Arrays.asList("Robin","Zax","John","Rohan"); String order = "OZJRHBAS";`

OUTPUT: ["Zax","John","Rohan","Robin"]

```
 names.stream().sorted(new MyComparator(order)).collect(Collectors.toList()).forEach(System.out::println);
```

I just want the implementation of compare method below is what i have tried but its sorting on the basis of only first letter. Is there any way it can be done in such a way the all the letters of string are taken care for sorting.

```
class MyComparator implements Comparator<String> {
    private String order;

    MyComparator(String order) {
        this.order = order;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        char[] charsOfS1 = s1.toCharArray();
        char[] charsOfS2 = s2.toCharArray();
        int proximity = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<Math.min(charsOfS1.length,charsOfS2.length);i++){
            int check = order.indexOf(s1.charAt(i)) - order.indexOf((s2.charAt(i)));
            if(check<0)
                proximity--;
            else if(check>0)
                proximity++;
        }
        return proximity;
    }
}
```

Comment: "I just want the implementation of compare method" - okay, so what are the actual requirements? How far have you got in implementing them? We really don't have nearly enough information to help you at the moment.

Comment: *given alphabetical order using stream and comparator* -> `"Zax","John","Robin"` or `"Zax","Robin","John"` !! for a solution maybe -> `return o2.compareTo(o1);`

Comment: just take the 1st char of each name, get their positions in the order string, and compare the 2 positions themselves

Comment: @JonSkeet  I just want to make use of order given for sorting the string names in compare method, If i do  return o2.compareTo(o1); it will not sort it in given order it will sort it in default alphabetical order.

Comment: That's not a complete set of requirements though. How would you compare "Robin" and "Roger" for example? And have you *tried* implementing the requirements? This feels like a homework question without any indication of you trying it first - please see https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion, But I have added the snippet of what I have tried @JonSkeet

Comment: That clearly doesn't use `order` *at all*. It just compares the strings in the default way. Have you tried anything goes anywhere towards actually implementing the requirements?

Comment: ```@Override
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        char[] charsOfS1 = s1.toCharArray();
        char[] charsOfS2 = s2.toCharArray();
        int proximity = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<Math.min(charsOfS1.length,charsOfS2.length);i++){
            int check = order.indexOf(s1.charAt(i)) - order.indexOf((s2.charAt(i)));
            if(check<0)
                proximity--;
            else if(check>0)
                proximity++;
        }
        return proximity;
    }```

Comment: @JonSkeet you can refer above solution I have tried and tested.

Comment: Don’t post you code as comment. [Edit] your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply compare the index position of the first character of strings:

```
public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
    return order.indexOf(s1.charAt(0)) - order.indexOf((s2.charAt(0)));
}
```

**Full Demo**:

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

class MyComparator implements Comparator<String> {
    private String order;

    MyComparator(String order) {
        this.order = order;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        return order.indexOf(s1.charAt(0)) - order.indexOf((s2.charAt(0)));
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        List<String> names = Arrays.asList("Robin", "Zax", "John");
        String order = "ZJR";
        System.out.println(names.stream().sorted(new MyComparator(order)).toList());
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
[Zax, John, Robin]
```

Comment: But if you compare only charAt(0) it will sort it on the basis of first letter for example: `  List<String> names= Arrays.asList("Robin","Zax","John","Rohan");
        String order = "OZJRHBAS"; ` the OUTPUT will be Zax
John
Robin
Rohan  but here Rohan should come before Robin.

Comment: @vishal: It's almost as if you haven't provided complete requirements...